# comparing start date with in the same list using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have class called LaborRate as below. It has Id, start date, end date column.

user can see existing records from database table in a grid and he can edit them and/or he can add new records to the grid.

while saving existing modified records or new records I need to do below validation.

If the Start Date or End Date falls within Start Date & End Date on other record for then I need to through some error. I cannot depend on Id column because for newly added record the id value is -1. What is the best method to do this comparison.

```
    public class LaborRate
{
    private int _id;
    private decimal _laborRate;
    private DateTime _StartDate;
    private DateTime _EndDate;

    public int Id
    { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }

    public Decimal Rate
    { get { return _laborRate; } set { _laborRate = value; } }

    public DateTime StartDate
    { get { return _StartDate; } set { _StartDate = value; } }

    public DateTime EndDate
    { get { return _EndDate; } set { _EndDate = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Could just use Linq. X=x.StartDate > startDate || x.EndDate < endDate where x is the context of the db or something to that effect. As an fyi, that ID will never be null 

Comment: I did this. LaborRate.Select(x => LaborRate.Where(y => y.StartDate >= x.StartDate && y.EndDate <= x.StartDate).Count() > 0).ToList() ... But I am not sure how to avoid current record. And Id will be -1 when user trying to add new record.

Comment: If the current record isn’t saved yet then why do you need to avoid it? Just read from the database and check if the count is greater than 0? Also, you don’t need the select, just do a where, the select is pretty useless in this situation

Comment: Also, you don’t need all of those private variables in C#. Having public int Id { get; set; } implicitly creates a private variable in the background. Makes the code cleaner 

Comment: if add 10 new records today I want to compare that 10 new records as well. before saving to DB

Comment: So you have multiple sources of information? A database with saved records and another list with not saved records? Could you share a bit more code as I’m not following what you’re trying to do to be honest

Comment: modified post please check.

Comment: Ok, so I would say you’re doing this is a rather complicated way. By doing a bulk edit or bulk add, you need to be able to differentiate in your model what has changed, currently you can’t tell what data has been edited. I would change the logic to save per record rather than in bulk. Otherwise, you’d need a way to specify what fields have been edited because I don’t see a way for you to do what you want with your current model